# Create a .eml file in Python

Tags: python, centos, eml

Anybody knows how to do this? I got all the information of the email (body, subject, from , to, cc, bcc) and need to generate an .eml file out of it.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a description, a link, or some other indication of what an '.eml' file is or what software produces and consumes it?

Comment: here -> http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/EML-Microsoft-Outlook-Express-mail-message-MIME-RFC-822

Comment: Do you have the data stored in an `email.message.Message`? If so, just do: `open('output.eml', 'w').write(str(my_message))`.